# Can my licensed NY driver, age 17, drive in VA?

Tags: usa, driving, driving-licenses, new-york-state, virginia

My daughter is traveling to VA; she has a valid NYS license.  Can she drive in VA?

Comment: Only if her parents let her. :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton *snarky comments withheld* :)

Comment: Does your driver have a class DJ, MJ, or DJMJ license or permit, issued by NYS DMV?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Virginia DMV](https://www.dmv.virginia.gov/drivers/#restrictions.asp) there are restrictions placed on the driver's under 18 licensed in or out of state:

> **Curfew Restrictions**
>
> If you are under age 18, Virginia law prohibits you from driving midnight to 4 A.M. except when driving:
>
> - to or from a place of business where you are employed;
> - to or from an activity that is supervised by an adult and is sponsored by a school or by a civic, religious, or public organization;
> - with a licensed spouse age 18 or older, parent or other adult acting in loco parentis who is occupying the front passenger seat,
> - in case of an emergency, including responding to emergency calls as a volunteer firefighter or rescue squad personnel.

and

> **Restrictions on the Number of Passengers**
>
> If you are under age 18, you may carry only one passenger under age 21, unless accompanied by a licensed parent, or other adult acting in place of a parent, in the front passenger seat. However, after you have held your license for one year, you may carry up to three passengers under age 21 in the following situations:
>
> - Travel to and from a school-sponsored activity;
> - A licensed driver 21 or older is in the front passenger seat; or
> - **In case of an emergency.**
>
> Learner's permit holders may not carry more than one passenger under age 18.
>
> (Passenger restrictions do not apply to family members)
>
> Violations of either the curfew or passenger restrictions can result in the suspension of your driver's license.

Comment: I don't think Virginia can suspend an out of state license, so that last paragraph would only apply to Virginians.

Comment: No but they request NY to suspend the license.